# Where can I get this wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

On the Ubuntu website, next to the "Download Ubuntu" link, there is [this picture of a laptop](http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/1274/u/img/homepage/Dell_XPS_Laptop_Front.png). It has a wallpaper that I think I remember being the default of an earlier version or something, but I don't know which. I have been unable to find this wallpaper in any archives of ubuntu's default wallpapers, so I'm wondering where on earth it came from and where I can get it.

Comment: A very good link for Ubuntu Wallpers is http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/category/wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

This is the default wallpaper of ubuntu 14.10.You can find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4FmH.jpg).

Comment: No, the one pictured on the website is not the default.

Comment: Is this the wallpaper that you are looking for?